# "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when deploying Rails with Capistrano

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am standing up a new Ubuntu server running MySQL. I have Capistrano set up on my development server and am trying to deploy:cold after running deploy:setup. After the deploy script tries to run

```
executing "cd /home/adm1n/www/knowit/releases/20121112152400 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
```

I keep getting this message:

```
Rake Aborted!
Access denied for user 'specialusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

I have 'specialusername' created in my database on the mysql server for both localhost and %.
I removed the empty user ' ' @ localhost row in the user database.
I have added the IP address of the server to my my.cnf file and commented out the 127.0.0.1 line.

Here is my deploy.rb file for production:

```
production:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: mydatabasename
username: specialusername
password: crazypassword
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

I think that I may not be understanding how this works. On my Site5 server I have never had to specify which host I was accessing mysql from. But in all my reading it seems that I must specify a specific user@hostname. This makes it a little difficult if I am deploying from many different locations around the country as I travel. OR do I merely need to use the hostname of my laptop regardless of my current IP address? Thanks for any insight and solutions you can provide. I have not found any articles that have provided me precisely what I need to fix this issue.

Comment: can you log in using the MySQL client?

Comment: capistrano executes the deployment on the server that you deploy to. check if that server is able to login using your credentials form the command line using ```mysql -up```

Comment: The mysql server is the same server as my web server (Passenger). When I ssh into the mysql server and run: `mysql -u knowitdbadmin -p -h192.168.0.50` I am able to log in to mysql. However, if I simply run `mysql -u knowitdbadmin -p` I receive this message: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'knowitdbadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES). In my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file I have: bind-address: 192.168.0.50. I have also tried using 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to connect to a MySQL server.

First, using a UNIX socket, such as `/tmp/mysql.sock`, in which case there is no "host", so authentication uses `username@localhost`. This will work only with connection from the same machine.

Second, using a TCP/IP connection. In this case, the server listen to a specific port on the box running the database, and the way to connect to it is to provide a host + port number. The port number can be optional (the default will be used), and host can be given by hostname or by ip address. This allows to connect locally or remotely.

Note: I have no way to actually verify this (no access to your server), so below is just a possible explanation ...

In `mysql -u knowitdbadmin -p -h192.168.0.50`, a host (-h) is given, so TCP/IP is used, causing authentication to use `username@hostname` or `username@%` rules, but this will not use `username@localhost`.

In `mysql -u knowitdbadmin -p`, no host (-h) is given, so the default UNIX socket is used, causing authentication to use `username@localhost` (and therefore fails).

If you want to disable access using a UNIX socket (/tmp/mysql.sock) and username@localhost, and always use a TCP/IP connection, do it all the way:
* remove grants to username@localhost (done)
* always specify a host/IP (+ port) in configuration files from your application.

I think the problem is with:

```
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

try using a hostname + port number instead.

As a side note, if you somehow have SQL access to the database itself, starting with 5.5, a new table `performance_schema.host_cache` will show you all the reasons a connection is failing, which saves a lot of time when troubleshooting things like this.

Comment: So if the server I'm deploying to is also the MySQL server, then option 1 should still be available to me, no?

Comment: @steve, I don't know enough how rake works, but from a pure mysql connection point of view, that should be fine too. Try adding a grant to username@localhost then. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, @MarcAlff, granting usage to username@localhost worked! I also changed my my.cnf file bind-address back to 127.0.0.1 and restarted mysqld. I could swear I granted to that user before, but clearly I did not. So now I have a new issue. Rake is aborting still with this message: uninitialized constant DBC

Comment: @steve, Glad to hear this helped and that the connect part is solved. I do not know rake enough to help about this new issue, and you will most likely get better help with a separate question on this. Since the Access denied error is solved, don't forget to accept and/or upvote this answer. Regards.